# What does this mean? getData([renderData]);

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me understand the logic behind this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getData([renderData]);
});


function renderData(JSON) {
    $.each(JSON, function(i, item) {
    //logic
    }
}

 function getData(callBacks) {
    var url= '/data/data2';
    $.getJSON(url, function() {
    }).done(function(JSON) {
        if(callBacks) {
            for( var i = 0; i < callBacks.length; i++ ) {
                callBacks[i](JSON);
            }
        }       
    }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        //alert(xhr.responseText);
    }); 
 }
```

Is the function renderData getting set as its own parameter?

Thank you.

Comment: There is not enough context to say anything concrete. You may add definition of `getData` function to make the logic more clear.

Comment: @Oriol added getData

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's passing the function `renderData`, inside an array, to another function called `getData`.

note thats its passing the function and not calling anything, so the array holds a reference to the function and not it's return value, inside `getData` the `renderData` function can be called by accessing the first value of the array passed as an argument.

i.e. `callBacks[i](JSON); //callBacks[i] is renderData`

Looking at `getData` it would seem that it's been done this way to avoid another layer of nesting inside the ajax calls/responses making the code more readable (once you understand it that is).

Comment: so when I call callBacks[i](JSON) JSON is set as the parameter to the function renderData()? what if I had two parameters?

Comment: Thats correct, you can add more parameters by: `renderData(JSON, newParam1, newParam2)` etc and pass them to the callback, i.e. `callBacks[i](JSON, newParam1, newParam2);`

Comment: This is amazing, I had no idea! Guess you learn something new everyday! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

`getData` loads asynchronously some `JSON` and then calls any amount of callbacks you need (through an array) when everything is loaded. Any callback will be called with the loaded data as first parameter.

In this case, `renderData` is the only callback given.